# show raspberry pi terminal on the android terminal over usb?

Tags: android, terminal, raspberry-pi

is it possible to get the raspberry pi 3 terminal, over the terminal cable from the raspberry pi, to the terminal on my android device?

Thanks

Comment: `the terminal cable`. Please tell how such a cable looks like.

Comment: https://www.google.nl/search?q=raspberry+pi+console+cable&client=ms-android-om-lge&prmd=sivn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi79qLkhfDOAhWH2hoKHYH1AL4Q_AUICCgC&biw=360&bih=517#imgrc=FdUk-TrjhruMdM%3A

Comment: That cable does not fit my Android devices.

Comment: ??  http://img.dxcdn.com/productimages/sku_162930_2.jpg

Comment: My devices would not be able to provide the current for the Raspberry. How are you doing?

Comment: power the raspberry pi just by his own power suply

Comment: In the Play Store there are several app with which you can comunicate with the raspi.

Comment: but that is over wifi

Comment: And can you make a connection over the cable? I wonder why you dont tell more about what you have done already. I have to pull every word out of you.

Comment: Sorry, i'm looking for a way to access my raspberry pi even if i don't have access to the wifi so i can program or make changes on it. I came accross the "usb to ttl" cable and tought this might be a solution, but i dont have the cable yet so i can't test it. And i was wondering why you did not know how to attach a usb cable to an android device.

Comment: Does not matter what i know. The point was that you should make clear what you have and what you want. Now with that OTG cable your device should support OTG to begin with. You have said nothing about OTG.  So i keep pulling.

Comment: So, do you know an other way to attach a usb device to an android device????

Comment: Please react to the point. You can attach it in this way yes. But your device has to support OTG. Why dont you react on that?

Comment: Yes, it supports OTG